# Requests connection error after blackouts

Tags: python, docker, python-requests, raspberry-pi-zero

We have several Raspberry PI Zero in which we installed docker with we run a python 3.9 container. This runs a Bluetooth scanner, sends data online with requests and do other stuff. All works well until there are blackouts in the places where they are placed and requests go nuts. The PIs restart, docker goes up, it starts the container but at the moment it has to call my server with any `requests.get/post`, it always gives these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xb538aeb0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

and

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mywebsite.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /devices (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xb538aeb0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

If I restart the container it returns to work fine. Thinking it had something to do with the provider we are using, I set the DNS of the PIs with Cloudflare ones but if it was the cause I would had this problem always and not after the blackouts. Does anyone know how I could fix it?